# Regression testing automation on IBM MobileFirst with Mobile Test Workbench

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, rational-test-workbench

My team and I are looking for the possibility of performing regression testing automation.

We are working with the IBM MobileFirst Platform and started using the Mobile Test Workbench in order to execute functional tests. Our main goal is to use the recording capabilities of that plugin in order to run scheduled tests. Does anyone know if this is possible? I wasn't able to find that information at the IBM Knowledge Center.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok. Just found the info. Thank you Yoel for the links you sent. They did not answer the question completely, but gave me the path to what I was looking for.

It is in fact not possible to schedule tests from the **MobileFirst Platform Test Workbench**, which is NOT directly the Rational Test Workbench, since we're using Eclipse Kepler SR2 and do not have a license for RTW.

So, considering that we are using the tool that can be downloaded freely from the Eclipse Marketplace (See: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-mobilefirst-platform-test-workbench), we have the possibility of running a test with the cmdline.bat tool (See: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS2HS7_8.7.0/com.ibm.rational.test.lt.common.doc/topics/truncmdln.html?lang=en). In the end, you can schedule the execution of that shell command with the Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

YES, it is possible and you can find more information from the following links:

**Running mobile tests from a schedule**

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS2HS7_8.7.0/com.ibm.rational.test.lt.mob.rtwm.ditaval.doc/topics/trun_mobtest_schedule.html?lang=en

**Rational Test Workbench Mobile Test Edition**

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS2HS7_8.7.0/com.ibm.rational.test.lt.mob.rtwm.ditaval.doc/rtwm_version_welcome.html

**Testing with IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation**

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.test.doc/test/c_wl_mobile_test_ovw.html

Comment: We do not have the Rational Test Workbench, we are using the IBM MobileFirst Test Workbench, which seems to be a little different, since I can't find the performance schedule option. Do you know if the Rational Test Workbench is freely distributed, like the MobileFirst one?

Comment: IBM MobileFirst Test Workbench is a subset of Rational Test Workbench. I think the schedule option is not available on IBM MobileFirst Test Workbench.

Comment: Thank you Leandro. Just sent an answer with the final result. And yes, it is not available for the plugin we are using.